# 'gsutil cp' returns Catching up md5 for resumed upload

Tags: google-cloud-storage

After my uploads got terminated for unknown reasons I try to resume them running the **gsutil cp** command again and all I get is the following message

```
Catching up md5 for resumed upload
```

But nothing else happens, the process keep running but my transfers never resume

Comment: After 1 hour one of my uploads resumes although I'm still waiting for the others. I guess that building md5 over 200 GB files takes time. Is there no better way to handle upload resume?

Answer (score 3):

The resumable upload handler computes MD5s on the fly, while uploading files. If the upload completes without any interruptions (i.e., no resume attempts required), this works well. Unfortunately when resuming it's necessary to rebuild the MD5 state from scratch, or "catch up" to the resume point (which can take a long time for large files).

One optimization that would be possible would be to do the catch up in a thread, in parallel while the upload continues. If you (or anyone) is interested in implementing this, we're open for code submissions. See "gsutil help dev" for details about how to do that. Note that the code in question is actually in the boto library.

Comment: When you say it can take a long time. Does it take lesser time to start the download from scratch or is it quicker to wait for it to resume? filesize: 200 gb
filesize : 500 gb
and filesize 2000gb

Comment: Hi Yaseen - it wouldn't take less time to start from scratch because that would have to do the same MD5 computation and also re-upload the bytes. Resuming (and catching up the MD5 state) is strictly less work than starting over from scratch, and also saves network traffic.